# Calculate polar decompostion of a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

The [polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of a square complex matrix A is a matrix decomposition of the form

```
A = UP,
```

where U is a unitary matrix and P is a positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix. This differs from the [QR Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) implemented as [scipy.linalg.qr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html#qr-decomposition).

How can I find P with numpy/scipy?

Comment: The Numpy docs [claim](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html#qr-decomposition) that QR and polar decompositions are the same; if you're convinced of the opposite, you might want to start a discussion on one of their mailing lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the [wikipedia page on Polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) you linked to contains formulas to compute it from the SVD.

Secondly, a few paragraphs up from the one you linked to from the scipy linalg tutorial, it is explained how to compute the [SVD](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html#singular-value-decomposition).

So, by combining these two, you should have the polar decomposition, no?

Answer (score 3):

There is "scipy.linalg.polar" now :) 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.polar.html